# ¿Cómo obtener el número de serie del volumen del disco duro del servidor SQL SERVER por medio de una consulta?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Me gustaría saber si alguien ha encontrado la manera, o una función integrada que pudiese hacer que me extraiga información del disco duro donde esta instalada la base de datos.

Comment: Me temo que SQL server solo sirve para mantener datos y consultarlos. Si quieres tal cosa, necesitas hacerlo por medio de una aplicación externa. mira este link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1353881/how-do-i-use-c-sharp-to-get-the-hard-disk-serial-number

Comment: Hola eberlast, a pesar de ser una buena pregunta carece de trabajo de investigación. Para futuros casos te recomiendo poner algunos ejemplos de las cosas que hayas intentado, páginas que has visitado, teniendo esta información verás que más de un usuario se animará a ayudarte y tus preguntas tendrán mayor atención :D

Comment: Gracias por sus atenciones amigos. Bueno, por ahora lo hice en c# en una mini aplicación de consola, con ello puedo generar una licencia de uno de las aplicaciones que manejo, pero tengo que ejecutarlo en el servidor para hacer todo eso, y me parecía super excelente que no fuese así, pero bueno, ya encontrare la mejor manera de optimizarlo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vengo a responder mi propia pregunta por si a alguien le es de utilidad, a todos los que respondieron, gracias pero si se puede hacer la consulta desde SQL Server, para ello hay que hacer lo siguiente:

1. Habilitar la ejecucion de comandos Shell en SQL Server:

   ```
   -- Para permitir el cambio de opciones avanzadas.
   EXEC sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1;
   GO;
   -- Para actualizar el valor configurado actualmente para las opciones avanzadas.
   RECONFIGURE;
   GO;
   -- Para habilitar la función de ejecución de comandos shell en sql server.
   EXEC sp_configure 'xp_cmdshell', 1;
   GO;
   -- Para actualizar el valor configurado actualmente para esta característica.
   RECONFIGURE;
   GO;
   ```
2. Ejecutar en SQL Server el comando equivalente a hacerlo desde la consola de windows "VOL":

   `DECLARE @tbl TABLE(dir_lines VARCHAR(200))
   DECLARE @Cmd VARCHAR(2000)
   SET @cmd = 'dir "' + (SELECT NAME FROM sys.dm_os_loaded_modules WHERE DESCRIPTION like 'SQL Server%' AND NAME LIKE '%sqlservr.exe') + '"'
   INSERT INTO @tbl
   EXEC xp_cmdshell @cmd
   SELECT LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(REPLACE(dir_lines,'-',''), CHARINDEX(':',dir_lines)+1,LEN(dir_lines)))) AS SERIAL  FROM @tbl WHERE dir_lines like '%volume%serial%' or dir_lines like '%serie%volume%'`

Comment: Recuerda aceptar tu propia respuesta una vez transcurrido el tiempo de espera!

Comment: El resultado que obtienes, es el mismo que si ejecutaras `EXEC xp_cmdshell 'vol'`

Answer (score 0):

SQL server no tiene ninguna función/stored procedure nativo para obtener esta información, deberías programar un CLR en C# en integrarlo al server para poder luego invocarlo. [Este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11500934/find-hard-disk-serial-number-from-remote-sql-server-installed-hard-disk) te puede dar una idea. De cualquier forma, si lo que intentas es implementar algún algoritmo de seguridad (tipo DRM), el número de serie puede ser muy relativo, hoy por hoy es sumamente común que los SQL Server corran sobre ambientes virtualizados, dónde el # de serie del disco o no existe o eventualmente se podría modificar.

Answer (score 0):

Para los que se preguntan como hice para obtener el serial en C# aquí les dejo mi codigo que me ha servido hace largo rato:

`public string GetHDDSerial()
{
    try
    {
        string serial = "";
        DirectoryInfo currentDir = new DirectoryInfo(Environment.CurrentDirectory);
        string unidad = currentDir.Root.Name.Replace("\", "");
        string path = string.Format("win32_logicaldisk.deviceid=\"{0}\"", unidad);
        ManagementObject disk = new ManagementObject(path);
        disk.Get();
        serial = disk["VolumeSerialNumber"].ToString();
        return serial;
    }
    catch (Exception ex) { Console.WriteLine(ex.Message); return string.Empty; }
}`

Answer (score -1):

El número de serie de un disco duro ***sí es posible obtenerlo*** desde una consulta de SQL Server ejecutando el procedimiento almacenado `xp_cmdshell`:

```
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'vol'
```

Puedes corroborar esta información tecleando en la consola de comandos (`cmd.exe`):

```
>vol C:
```

Donde `C:` es la letra de la unidad que deseas consultar el número de serie.

Comment: el preguntó por el serial del disco duro, no por el [serial del volumen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volume_serial_number), son diferentes. volume serial parte del formato de windows (FAT, NTFS). El numero de serie del disco duro es puesto por el fabricante. Mediante programacion se puede obtener por medio de [Win32_DiskDrive](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394132(v=vs.85).aspx). Ahora si lo que quiere el OP es el volume, tiene que editar la pregunta, ya que podría llevar a confusión :P

Comment: En base a la preguntaría faltaría saber en que unidad (A:, B:, ...) de **serie de volumen** está instalado la BD.